# How to return a Kotlin Coroutines Flow in Spring reactive WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

Spring 5.2 brought Kotlin coroutines support, Spring reactive `WebClient` has got Coroutines supports in Kotlin extensions.

I have created backend service which exposes GET `/posts` as a Flow, check the codes [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-kotlin-coroutines-sample/blob/master/data-r2dbc/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.kt#L97-L100).

```
@GetMapping("")
fun findAll(): Flow<Post> =
        postRepository.findAll()
```

In the client sample, I tried to use WebClient to consume this api by the following.

```
@GetMapping("")
suspend fun findAll(): Flow<Post> =
        client.get()
                .uri("/posts")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .awaitExchange()
                .awaitBody()
```

It failed due to a Jackson serialization of the Flow type.

Due to awaitXXX method in the above expression, I have to use a `suspend` modifier for this fun.

But the following is working if I changed the body type to Any, check the [compelete codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-kotlin-coroutines-sample/blob/master/webclient/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.kt#L42-L48).

```
GetMapping("")
suspend fun findAll() =
        client.get()
                .uri("/posts")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .awaitExchange()
                .awaitBody<Any>()
```

After read [the Kotlin Coroutines](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#coroutines) of spring ref doc, the Flux should be converted to Kotlin coroutines Flow.  How to deal with return type to a Flow and remove `suspend` here?

**Update**: The return type is changed to Flow, check the latest [source codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-kotlin-coroutines-sample/blob/master/webclient/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.kt#L46-L52) here, I think it could be part of Spring 5.2.0.M2. The `suspend` modifier is required for 2-stage coroutines operations in webclient api, as explained below by Sébastien Deleuze.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that returning `Flow` does not require using suspending functions for the handler method itself. With `Flow`, the suspending functions are usually isolated in lambda parameters. But in this (common) use case, due to `WebClient` 2 stage API (first get the response, then get the body) we need the handler method to be suspending for `awaitExchange` and then get the body as `Flow` with `bodyToFlow` extension:

```
@GetMapping("")
suspend fun findAll() =
    client.get()
        .uri("/posts")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .awaitExchange()
        .bodyToFlow<Post>()
```

This is supported as of Spring Framework 5.2 M2 and Spring Boot 2.2 M3 (see [related issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22820)). See also my [related detailed blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow).

Comment: Why not add a bodyToFlow on exchange directly?

Comment: `WebClient` is a 2 stage API because what you do with the body could depend of processing of other information like the response status or headers. I have commited the fix on master feel free to test.